# C# - Is the amount of objects in memory affecting performance of local processing?

Tags: c#, performance

I am very confused by what I am seeing in my program.

Let's say we have a list of two large objects (loaded from 2 external files).

Then I iterate over each object and for each one I call a method, which performs a bunch of processing.

Just to illustrate:

```
    foreach (var object in objects)
    {
        object.DoSomething();
    }
```

In first case, objects contains 2 items. It completes very fast, I track the progress of each object individually and the processing for each one is very fast.

Then I run the program again, this time adding some more input files, so instead of 2, I'd have let's say 6 objects.

So the code runs again, and the 2 objects from before are still there, along with some more, but for some odd reason, now each processing (each call to object.DoSomething()) takes much longer than before.

- Let's say scenario 1 with 2 objects, objectA.Dosomething() takes 1
  minute to complete.
- Let's say scenario 2, with 6 objects, same    objectA.Dosomething()
  as in scenario 1 now takes 5 minutes to    complete.

The more objects I have in my list, the longer each processing for each individual object takes.

How is that possible? How can the performance of an individual processing for a specific, independent object, be affected so much by objects in the memory? How can, in scenario 1 and 2 above, the exact same processing on the exact same data take a significantly different amount of time to complete?

Also, please note that processing is slower from the start, it does not start fast on first object and then slows down progressively, it's just consistently slowed down proportionally to the amount of objects to process. I have some multi-threading in there, and I can see the rate at which threads complete drops dramatically when I start adding more objects. The multi-threading happens inside of "DoSomething()" and it will not leave untill all threads have completed. However, I don't think this issue is related to multi-threading. Actually, I added multi-threading because of the slowness.

Also please note that initially I was merging all input files into one huge object and one single call to DoSomething(), and I broke it down thinking it would help performance.

Is this a "normal" behavior and if so, what are the ways around this? I can think of other ways to process the data, but I still don't get this behavior and there has to be something I can do to get the intended result here.

**Edit 1:**
Each object in the "objects" list above also contains a list (queue) of smaller objects, around 5000 of those each. I am starting to believe my issue might be that, and that I should use structs or something similar instead of having so many nested objects. Would that explain the type of behavior I am describing above?

Comment: Sounds like you need to attach a profiler and see what is actually causing the slowness, rather than guessing and throwing threads at it.

Comment: One possibility is worse reference locality and higher GC pressure due to more memory being taken by the big objects. If that is the case, you can load the objects from files one by one as you iterate, e.g. by using `IEnumerable` with iterator lazy-loading the files.

Comment: Its hard to say for sure with what you've given us.  If the `DoSomething` method is IO bottlenecked then you will see each individual iteration become slower.  If you are not disposing any `IDisposable` or implementing `using` statements properly you will also see a progressive slowdown.

Comment: This is so abstract its hard to say. I've seen programs slow considerably when they use so much memory they start paging out to disk. How big is each object? You'll need to collect some diagnostics and/or attach a profiler.

Comment: I understand this is vague, I was hoping maybe there is something simple I am missing out on, as this behavior makes no sense to me. A list of objects for which processing is needed, one object processed at a time, but the objects individually take much longer to complete if there are more objects in memory/list, even though this is all independent processing, done sequentially. I don't see a progressive slow down, performance is consistently slower proportionally to the amount of data, from very first call to DoSomething() it is slower, and then it just maintains that slowness,

Comment: *Between objects loading and the foreach loop, try to execute the following instructions*: GC.Collect() ; GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() ; GC.Collect() ;

Comment: I am already calling it, but I am not calling GC.Collect() after GC.WaitForpendenFinalizers(), should I? Currently I am calling this before the loop: GC.Collect() ; GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() ;

Comment: Regarding how big the objects are, on average they are each created from an excel file containing around 5000 rows (loaded with spreadlight SpreadsheetLight, and with a propoer "using" clause, so file is out of scope after object is loaded). One thing that might be worth adding is that those objects are like the placeholders, but inside of them, there is one more custom Object for each original row, so each object contains around 5000 objects in a queue. Would it better to forget about those nested objects and use something like struct instead?

Comment: To the downvoters: I thought the behavior I am getting was interesting enough to share with you guys, but apparently some people think I was wrong to bring it up here. I described the high level scenario and high level behavior, is that wrong? I wanted to see if what I was telling would ring any bell for someone who might have experienced something similar. Some people they ask "how do I append strings" and they get upvotes, But oh well, I get it, next time I keep this to myself and I use a profiler.

Comment: C# is pretty good at handling small objects, however there is a limited space in memory. Your objects will first beloaded into L1 on the CPU cash, when its full. They will be moved down to L2, when that is full, then to L3 and lastly to memory. To speed up the process, it might be a good idea, to remove references to objects when you are done using them. If its large objects. They might go straight to the Ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, my question was too abstract for any precise answer to be given. I mostly wanted some pointers and to know if somehow I might have hit some internal limit.

It turned out I was overlooking a separate mechanism I have for logging results internally and producing reports. I built that part of the system really quickly and it was ridiculously inefficient and growing way too fast. Limiting the size of the internal structures, limiting the amount of retrievals from big collections and breaking down the processing in smaller chunks did the trick.

Just to illustrate, something that was taking over 6 hours is now taking 1 minute. Shame on me. Cleaner solution would be to use a database, but at least it seems I will be getting away with this one for now.